# How to add namespaces to root node in SQL Server 2005 using XML FOR PATH

Tags: sql-server-2005, xml-namespaces, for-xml-path

I've created Select...FOR XML PATH statement using SQL Server 2005 and need to add several namespaces and schema reference to the root node.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://somewhere/v1/ schemaname.xsd"
xmlns="http://somewhere/v1/"
xmlns:lom="http://somewhere/lom/v1/"
xmlns:a="http://somewhere/a/v1/"
xmlns:cf="http://somewhere/cf/v1/"
xmlns:co="http://somewhere/co/v1/"
xmlns:hx="http://somewhere/hx/v1/" 
xmlns:m="http://somewhere/m/v1/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
with xmlnamespaces
  (
   default 'http://somewhere/v1/',
  'http://somewhere/lom/v1/' as lom,
  'http://somewhere/a/v1/' as a,
  'http://somewhere/cf/v1/' as cf,
  'http://somewhere/co/v1/' as co,
  'http://somewhere/hx/v1/' as hx,
  'http://somewhere/m/v1/' as m,
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi
  )
select 'http://somewhere/v1/ schemaname.xsd' as "@xsi:schemaLocation"

for xml path('element')
```

Result:

```
<element xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:m="http://somewhere/m/v1/" 
         xmlns:hx="http://somewhere/hx/v1/" 
         xmlns:co="http://somewhere/co/v1/" 
         xmlns:cf="http://somewhere/cf/v1/" 
         xmlns:a="http://somewhere/a/v1/" 
         xmlns:lom="http://somewhere/lom/v1/" 
         xmlns="http://somewhere/v1/" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://somewhere/v1/ schemaname.xsd" />
```